# How to concat 2 values inside a loop thymeleaf

Tags: loops, spring-boot, thymeleaf, concatenation

I have some problems concatenating 2 values in thymeleaf

I do the following:

```
<tr th:each="p , in: ${info}">
<td th:utext="${p.nombre}">...</td>
<td th:utext="${p.preferencias.get(0).getNombrePref()} +'-'+ ${p.preferencias.get(1).getNombrePref()}">...</td>
<td th:utext="${p.email}">...</td>
</tr>
```

[This is how the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJcbE.jpg)

As you can see this is not dynamic because if `p.preferencias` size is bigger than 2 this will be a problem and the same if is less than 2

this what i tried :

```
<tr th:each="p , in: ${info}">
<td th:utext="${p.nombre}">...</td>
<td th:each="a , arcd : ${p.preferencias}" th:utext="${p.preferencias.get(arcd.index).getNombrePref()}">...</td>
<td th:utext="${p.email}">...</td>
</tr>
```

This is what i got:

[And got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMalp.jpg)

As you can see the second value move to email :(  then i thought in concat the values and try this :

```
<tr th:each="p , in: ${info}">
<td th:utext="${p.nombre}">...</td>
<td th:each="a , arcd : ${p.preferencias}" th:utext="${p.preferencias.get(arcd.index).getNombrePref()} + '-' +${p.preferencias.get(arcd.index).getNombrePref()} " >...</td>
<td th:utext="${p.email}">...</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the result:

[Result 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Doe.jpg)

I dont know how to concat the values and keep those in one cell 
How can i execute the loop to get all the values inside `p.preferencias` variable ?

EDIT:
post wrong image in result 3 now is the correct image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve the problem the tag `td` stay open thats why the secon value in the each iteration fill the next cell solve it using a `span` tag and iterate inside

```
<tr th:each="p , in: ${info}">
    <td th:utext="${p.nombre}">...</td>
    <td>
        <span th:each="a , arcd : ${p.preferencias}" th:utext="${p.preferencias.get(__${arcd.index}__).getNombrePref()} +  (${arcd.size-1 > arcd.index}? ', ':'')"></span>
    </td>
    <td th:utext="${p.email}">...</td>
</tr>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKpIt.png)